# php laravel Auth::attempt returns false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am using laravel 6 and authenticating my users by Auth class. following code returns false always. what is problem guys ?

```
    public function doLogin(Request $request){

    $authenticate = Auth::attempt([
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
    ]);

    if ($authenticate) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: may sound silly, but are the username and password correct? try `dd($request->all())` and make sure you have correct credentials.

Comment: @Shobi
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "GDBhY3PJWRk1ROd2QVb4DOQvumQsIX3axgaj29uA"
  "email" => "asd@asd.com"
  "password" => "123"
]
I have correct email and pass and there is in db

Answer (score 0):

You need to hash your password - by looking at your comment `"password" => "123"` - password is stored as plain text.

You can set up mutator in your `User` model to handle hashing automatically like so:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute(string $password): void
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
}
```

Make sure you import `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;`

You can then add new user or update existing via tinker - this should convert plain text password to hash and your authentication should be validating.